# Mongo DB C# Driver - Getting Translated BSON from C# code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Say I have the following cursor set up using the C# Driver:

```
     var cursor = _mongoClient.GetServer()
                               .GetDatabase("test")
                                .GetCollection<BsonDocument>("somecollection")
                                .Find(Query.EQ("field", "value"))
                                .SetFields(Fields.Exclude())
                                .SetLimit(5)
                                .SetSortOrder("field");
     var results = cursor.ToList();
```

I want to see the tranlated BSON command that gets sent to the mongo server (i.e. "db.somecollection.find({...})".

Either way is acceptable:

**1.** Some sort of function that will print this as a string.

**2.** Some way to "sniff" the command that gets sent to the server. *(The db profiling functionality in mongo.exe only shows the where clause and order by --I want to see everything --limit, field projections, etc)*

Also, doing this with a MongoQueryable would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var queryable= (MongoQueryable<BsonDocument>)someCollection;
var debug = queryable.GetMongoQuery().ToJson();
```

Comment: that will only show me the "where" part of the queryable. I wanted to see everything --where, sort, skip, limit, fields, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like the serialization of MongoCursor is encapsulated within classes internal to the MongoDB.Driver assembly. Therefore, serialized BSON messages that get sent to the server are not visible in client code, at least.

However, I can reasonably trust that the MongoCursor gets translated correctly at that lower level. (10gen is behind this project, after all.)

Of bigger concern is how LINQ expressions get translated. If I can verify that the LINQ IQueryables get translated to a MongoCursor with the correct state, I'm golden.

So, here is an extension method to pull the cursor out of the IQueryable:

```
    public static class MongoExtensions
    {

       public static MongoCursor GetCursor<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
       {
           var queryProvider = source.Provider as MongoQueryProvider;
           if (queryProvider == null)
           {
               throw new NotSupportedException("Explain can only be called on a Linq to Mongo queryable.");
           }

           var selectQuery = (SelectQuery)MongoQueryTranslator.Translate(queryProvider, source.Expression);

           if (selectQuery.Take.HasValue && selectQuery.Take.Value == 0)
           {
               throw new NotSupportedException("A query that has a .Take(0) expression will not be sent to the server and can't be explained");
           }

           var projector = selectQuery.Execute();

           var cursorProp = projector.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Cursor");
           return cursorProp.GetValue(projector) as MongoCursor<T>;

       }
    }
```

Then I can test the state of the MongoCursor, checking properties like "Query", "Skip", "Limit" and all the items in the "Options" collection.